# Use Fluent Interface with less Code

Tags: php, oop, laravel, fluent-interface

How can I reduce these two lines

```
$foo = new Bar();
$baz = $foo->methodOne('param')->methodTwo('param');
```

to

```
$baz = Bar::methodOne('param')->methodTwo('param');
```

I´ve seen this specially in Laravel and it´s nice readable Code. But I stuck getting this to work with some custom Helper-Classes. It feels like mixing static + nonstatic functions which is confusing for now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone passing by: Laravel offers a design pattern called Facades to achieve that effect. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades

If you want to build your own Helper-Class there are four things need:

1. Helper Class itself
2. Service Container binding of that class
3. Facade Class "pointing" to Service Container
4. Alias in app.php

Comment: This was all a bit too complex so Laravel came out with real-time facades to simply the creation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades#real-time-facades

Answer (score 3):

Laravel does it the following way

in: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Capsule`

```
/**
 * Dynamically pass methods to the default connection.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    return call_user_func_array(array(static::connection(), $method), $parameters);
}

/**
 * Get a connection instance from the global manager.
 *
 * @param  string  $connection
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Connection
 */
public static function connection($connection = null)
{
    return static::$instance->getConnection($connection);
}
```

From the [PHPDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic):

> __callStatic() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context.

I think you can simplify this for your class:

```
class Bar{
    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array(new Bar(), $method), $parameters);
    }
    public function hello(){
      echo "hello";
    }
}

Bar::hello();
```

Comment: After pasting in your snippet I´m still getting this: Non-static method Bar::methodOne() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context // any idea?

Comment: Am I right that `call_user_func_array(array(new Bar(), $method), $parameteres);`
cannot point to it´s own class? It should instanciate another class where - like in my example methodOne and methodTwo - are called. So it could be `call_user_func_array(array(new Foo(), $method), $parameters);` ... right?

Comment: Nope, it should work even if it points to its own class. I have edited my post with an example that works for me;

Comment: However, I see that you can't access to the $this in `hello()` . I don't know the solution however

Answer (score 2):

A more consistent and self explanatory thing to do would be to have a static construction function that returns the object, then call the methods on it like this:

```
$baz = Bar::create()->methodOne('param')->methodTwo('param');
```

An alternate syntax to do it directly with what you have now is:

```
$baz = (new Bar())->methodOne('param')->methodTwo('param');
```

But that's not very pretty...

Comment: Just stumbled upon this answer, your alternative solution may not be very _pretty_ (though thats a subjective matter), it is the cleanest way from all perspectives offered here. The overhead Laravel offers by using something _pretty_ as `Bar::nonStaticMethod()` is far more severe than `( new Bar() )->nonStaticMethod()`. Just write down the call-chain (versus your alternative solution) of how Laravel implemented its solution to something so simple and you'll consider not using it ;)

Comment: what exactly do you mean with severe?

Comment: @Kristo with `(new Bar())->methodCall()` there is no overhead. The _Facaded_ solution calls a static method which apparently does not exist, has to create an instance first of the called class `Bar` then to call the method with the instance with `call_user_func_array`, has to assign the parameters as an argumented array before it can return the instance itself to call any follow up (chained) calls. If you use `Bar::someMethod()` on various lines/position throughout your script, it does this process over and over again .. I would conclude it's pretty severe for something so simple ..